# Longitude and Latitude LOCF values in TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

If I store longitude and latitude as numeric values in 2 columns, can I get the average values of them with in a time bucket? and locf(last observation carry forward) value too? Will that average geo spatial value be accurate as it should not be just the mean value for co-ordinates?
What are the available functions for gps coordinates in timescaleDB?

Answer (score 1):

> can I get the average values of them within a time bucket? and locf(last observation carry forward) value too?

Yes, take a [locf](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#locf) function. It can also be combined with `avg` or any aggregation functions from Postgres.

> Will that average geospatial value be accurate as it should not be just the mean value for coordinates?

You can try to preview the values in a small set as this [example](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#locf-examples).

Also, almost all other Postgres extensions can be combined here. [PostGIS](https://postgis.net) is probably the most advanced extension for it.

Comment: I know about the locf and avg functions in TimescaleDB. But you can't just get the average of longitude and latitude in normal way as it it is getting distorted when you move closer to the poles of the earth. So this average calculation should be done differently, in a special way. Probably the PostGIS has all those functions suitable for the geo coordinates.